# How to stop line jumps in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I move the white line (see screenshot) in VScode that triggers a line break?

Now the code looks like this:

```
Padding(
     padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 8),
     child: TextFormField(
... etc ...
```

But I want it to look like:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15, top: 8),
    child: TextFormField(
... etc ...
```

This is a simple example, but in some cases I have this logic-based code that gets hard to read when the line breaks multiple times.

[Screenshot VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4H9yK.png)

Comment: What kind of formatter are you using? There are simple commands that allow you to stop auto-format for specific portions of code but they do differ from one formatter to another (e.g., prettier, beautify...)

Comment: @luco5826 the formatter came from Flutter. Formatting works nice. But I would like to move the line to the right

Comment: @luco5826 thank you! changing the formatting settings in the extension worked like a charm!